# What entitlements do I have if someone uses my video on Facebook and gets millions of views?

Tags: copyright

I posted a video on Facebook and a page asked if they could use the video. I said as long as I get credit. That video now has almost 10 million views on their page and countless other pages and sites have used my video. Am I entitled to any of the money they make off of advertisements? Are pages legally allowed to use that video if I did not give them license?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copyright law requires permission of the rights holder to e.g. post material. The terms of that permission could be very complicated, as seen in royalties contracts with publishers, but they can also be simple. If someone asks "can I post your video on my website" and you say "Sure, as long as you give me credit", then they can post the video on their site as long as that say something like "This video was made by Jake" or something like that. There is no exception to permission where permission is retroactively withdrawn just in case it turns out that one can make money off of the video.

However: you gave That Guy permission, and that does not mean that the hundreds of Other Guys have permission. So you can pursue all of the Other Guys and demand that they take the video down, or require some payment to get your permission.